# How to output permalink for term on WordPress posts in loop?

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I have a series of posts within a custom post type which are all have a term within the taxonomy "collection." Each post is associated with no more than one term within the "collection" taxonomy. I want to create a link under each post that says something like "More in this Collection," how can I dynamically create a link to the term that it belongs in?

When I use the following snippet, it shows a list of terms as links. I just need the permalink so I can create that custom link, and not the name of the term associated with it.

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'collection', '', ', ', '' ); ?>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a dynamic way to write something like this:

```
<a href="TERM_PERMALINK">More in this Collection</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're going to want to use `get_the_term` to get an array of the terms used for the post.  You can then loop through that array to create the permalinks.

```
get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'collection' )
```

This will return an array that fits the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => ...
            [name] => ...
            [slug] => ...
            [term_group] => ...
            [term_taxonomy_id] => ...
            [taxonomy] => collection
            [description] => ...
            [parent] => ...
            [count] => ...
        )
)
```

A simple loop through this array will allow you to parse your permalinks in whatever format you want, though I recommend `http://site.url/TAXONOMY/TERM` personally.

```
$collections = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'collection' );

foreach( $collections as $collection ) {
    $link = get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/collection/' . $collection->slug . '/';
    echo $link;
}
```

In my code snippet I'm echoing out the permalink.  You can do whatever you want with it (store it in an array, use it in a link definition, or really anything.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! That works perfectly! I modified it a bit to turn it into a link by adding some more stuff before and after the 'echo $link;' Also, I agree on the Taxonomy/Term permalink structure, that's what I meant initially. I thought this was a lost cause and was in the process of adding a bunch of manual 'if and then' statements! Thanks again!

Comment: This is incorrect, the answer by Tracker is better, and futureproof

Comment: No, this is not incorrect. It is just a different way to do the same thing. `get_term_link()` might be more effective, but you'll still need to perform a loop to get all the terms related for the post.  `get_term_link()` requires that you specify the term you're getting the link for, my method just retrieved the link manually rather than using the built-in function. Both are valid approaches.

Comment: If you use a different permalink structure this will break, better to use `get_term_link` and keep that possibility out of your templates.

Answer (score 13):

You can use **get_term_link()** function also.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link

Here is a small example:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy');

if (! empty($terms)) {
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $url = get_term_link($term->slug, 'my_taxonomy');
    print "<a href='{$url}'>{$term->name}</a>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Now that your answer has an example my answer looks redundant (thanks for the downvote btw) and my downvote on yours isn't deserved.  What do people do in such circumstances?

Comment: @MarcGuay, I am sorry to say that, but I was not downvoting you. You can check it on my repo graph, there is only one -2, by someone's downvote. I have upvoted your post to make it zero, but I can't cancel someone else downvote. And since I have edited my post you can cancel you downvote by pressing on your downvote. :) Too much downvotes in one comment.

Comment: Apologies for the false accusation!

Comment: Is there a reason for the "if (!empty )" check? Because if $terms is empty the foreach doesn't start --- so it seems to self-check.  If that is correct, then second question: Would "foreach( get_the_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy') as $term)" be equivalent? Because the get_the_terms gets executed only once I think, the $term keeps a pointer to that which advances each turn. Please tell/show if wrong!

Comment: @user3445853, no you can't use `get_the_terms()` as `foreach` argument, since it's result is not always array. Also `if (! empty($terms))` can be replaced by `if ($terms)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using get_term_link() and actually outputting the link as you described.

```
$collections = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'collection');

foreach ($collections as $collection){
    echo "<a href='".get_term_link($collection->slug, 'collection')."'>".$collection->name."</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

```
$cats = wp_get_post_terms($postId, 'cat name');
$category_link = get_term_link($cats[0]);
```